# How to use infragistics RecordFilter without UI

Tags: wpf, filter, code-behind, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Our users use infragistics WPF XamDataGrid to filter records. We serialize and store the filter settings as shown in [save the Recordfilters only](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/89812.aspx) to use them later. Now we want to use the filter without showing the XamDataGrid in the UI. The reason is that we want to disply a small icon with the number of filtered elements and the user shall only check the huge grid if the number is suspicious.

**Thus, we need to evaluate the RecordFilters with our DataSource to count the resulting elements. Either without XamDataGrid or at least with hidden XamDataGrid in code behind.**

So, what we can do is to check, if the RecordFilter hits a DataRecord, but how do we get the DataRecord?

```
_recordFilter.MeetsCriteria(_dataRecord)
```

If i create a whole XamDataGrid with all FieldLayouts and Fields in code behind and even bind the DataSource properly, it doesn't propagate the DataSource's Items to the grid's records. I just don't get it to evaluate and work in code behind.

```
_grid.DataContext.Count => 3
```

but

```
_grid.Records.Count => 0
```

and also

```
_grid.FieldLayouts[0].DataPresenter.Records => 0
```

So what to do? I see two possible solutions to this issue:

a) force the XamDataGrid in code behind to do it's magic and provide the needed DataRecords to check all filters with

```
_recordFilter.MeetsCriteria(_dataRecord)
```

b) find code that uses the RecordFilters directly on our data objects. This is certainly possible, but dificult since the RecordFilters use field-names and not property names of the objects...

Any ideas?